# How to generate random numbers between 1-10?

Tags: iphone, random, arc4random

Is it possible to generate a random numbers between 1 -10 but it should not be 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// ...

int i;

do {
   i = rand() % 10 + 1; // generate random number from 1 to 10
} while (i == 5);       // repeat until number != 5
```

Comment: Good answer but using arc4random() is much better because it will generate random numbers regardless of any seeding.. Using rand() without a unique seed will produce the same results each time the app is run.

Comment: I think better is subjective to the developer. What if they want the same sequence of random numbers each time.

Comment: @Danny: +1 - I didn't see any requirement in the question for a unique  sequence each time the program is run. Also `rand()` is more portable and it's relatively trivial to call `srand()` with an appropriate seed if needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
int x = arc4random()%9;
x += x>=4? 2 : 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to generate a random number between 1-10 using a system function and if it happens to be 5 generate it again until it is not the case. This solution has a minuscule probability that your function doesn't return until the iPhone batter dies :). The alternative is listed below

Another solution is to generate a random number using a system function between 1-9 and map 5-9 as 6-10

```
int GenRandomNumber()
{
    int x = GetSystemRandomBetween1and9();
    if ( x >= 5 )
      x += 1;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I like the second solution, didn't think of that. +1

Comment: how to map 5-9 as 6-10 please give an example, I am new to iphone.

Comment: I have updated the answer. you have to implement your own **GetSystemRandomBetween1and9**